# BS navbar not working with downloaded libraries of Bootstrap. fine with CDN

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to work with Bootstrap with downloaded libraries/Offline.

However written html works fine with CDN.

Here is the folder schema:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Output with CDN

[image]

Output without CDN

[image]

I tried with reinstalling of libraries(latest) but it didn't worked.

Please check once with Jquery and popper, because I guess these are causing issues.

The way i have linked those files please check it once.

Comment: Bring up your debugging tools in your browser and see if everything is loading as expected. See if there are errors in the console or network tab.